# mod_rewrite with Respond CMS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, respondcms

So I am trying to try out http://respondcms.com/ and I have got most of it installed and have got to directing my web server to: respondurl/test to test all of my settings.

The only one that is not working correctly is `mod_rewrite` It gives me no other errors.

I tried following the instructions here: http://respondcms.com/documentation/troubleshooting-installation but I received the following errors:

```
Server error!

 The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

 Error message: 
  /services/users/zstorage10p4/site_directory_hidden/atomplex/.htaccess:AllowOverride not allowed here

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

The instructions tell me to add the following to my `.htaccess`

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride FileInfo Options all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllowOverride` is not permitted in `.htaccess`. If those instructions really are what you say they are, they're wrong.

`AllowOverride` is a directive to be used in the `<directory>` sections of the main Apache configuration files to indicate which directives are permitted in `.htaccess` in that directory.

The Apache reference is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html)

Comment: Well in the documentation, the code in my question is wrapped in `<DIRECTORY /> </DIRECTORY>`

Comment: Read the documentation again. Those instructions tell you to place that in `httpd.conf`, not `.htaccess`. The error message you post is quite clear. It says '.htaccess: AllowOverride not allowed here`

Comment: Okay where would I find that file? I use a shared hosting.

Comment: The config file is usually in /etc/httpd/conf. If you're on a shared hosting service it's unlikely you'll have access to it, and highly likely that `.htaccess` will be enabled anyway. I think you should be looking at what's actually in your `.htaccess` file.